# SmartGwt : How to provide xml data to TreeGrid-DataSource?

Tags: gwt, tree, smartgwt, treegrid

How to provide xml data to  TreeGrid-DataSource ?

I have string which contains data in xml format.

String xmlData =

```
<List>
<employee>
    <EmployeeId>4</EmployeeId>
    <ReportsTo>1</ReportsTo>
    <Name>Charles Madigen</Name>
</employee>

<employee>
    <EmployeeId>192</EmployeeId>
    <ReportsTo>4</ReportsTo>
    <Name>Ralph Brogan</Name>
</employee>
</List>
```

DataSource required dataUrl i.e. dataComing form ServerSide.

what about clientSide if I have data in xml format ? How to set this data to TreeGrids dataSource ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This showcase example looks like  what you are doing http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_databinding_ondemand

Comment: In a given showcase example : xml file stored on client location. In my case I am generating xml as String and Want to pass this string to TreeGrid-DataSource

Comment: As you are only playing client side, I would suggest to build your tree in the same time as you are building your Xml string without using any DataSource and just provide tour TreeGrid with this Tree.

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE Thanks for reply. I already tried --> Tree tree = new Tree();tree.addList(listOfTreeNodeFromLeafToChild, parentNode); treeGridSeletced.setData(tree); but I got this message --> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
Script: http://127.0.0.1:8888/smartgwttree/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:114

Comment: I also tried targetTreeGrid.getTree().addList(listOfTreeNodeFromLeafToChild, parentNode); Still browser throwing msg : Unresponsive script + above msg in prev comment

Comment: @VaibhaV :hi vaibhav i am doing the same thing have u find any solution of this problem.If yes then please share with me.